# For loop over vector vectorized using C style pointers but not using iterators

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, vectorization

I have written a small piece of code that I use to accumulate the values of a vector which is faster than the std::accumulate because it allows the function to be vectorized. The main prerequisite for the function is that the vector is no longer used after the accumulation. The code is as follows:

```
template <typename floatType>
template <typename Iterator>
double Numeric_class<floatType>::AmDestructiveAccumulate(Iterator A, size_t length)
{
    if (length == 1)
    {
        return A[0];
    }

    Iterator temp_;
    while (length > 1)
    {
        if (length & 1) // odd
        {
            A[0] += A[length - 1]; // We add the last value which would otherwise be lost.
            length >>= 1;
            temp_ = A+length;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                A[i] += temp_[i];
            }
        }
        else // even
        {
            length >>= 1;
            temp_ = A+length;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                A[i] += temp_[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return A[0];
}
```

The function basically splits the vector in two halfs and takes the pairwise sum of the two halfs. After this it splits the summed first half in two equally long ranges and again sums the up pairwise and so on.

I used this function with `std::vector<double> data`. If I call it with A being data.data(). The vectorization tales place as expected and I also get a significant increase in execution speed. If I use data.begin(), no vectorization takes place. I compiled the code using VC2015 with full optimization. Is there a reason why it would be illegal to vectorized the iterator version of the code or does VC just not do it although it would be legal.

Comment: TBH it sounds like a horrible algorithm, and it's impressive that the optimizer manages to salvage at least some versions. You turned a linear-access O(N) algorithm into an O(N log N) variant with non-linear access.

Comment: @MSalters This is not correct. The access is still O(N). It's N+N/2+N/4+N/8 .... This geometric series converges to N*2. Furthermore, the access is linear within every iteration. And last but not least: Profiling shows an increase in performance for relevant N.

Comment: Fair point, it looked like two inner loops of length N/2, for odd and even, but only one of the two is used so it's not `N+2*(N/2)+4*(N/4)+...`.

Comment: gcc produces nearly identical object code for both versions. VS2015 produce rather different object files but not outrageously so, I see vectorized instructions in both cases.. Can you post your assembly listings for both versions at some paste bin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem is going to be `A[i] += temp_[i];`. Note that `A` and `temp` alias each other, but that your run-time choices of `[i]` means that this is only theoretical. Now, what does `[i]` actually mean? If `A` is a pointer, that's just shorthand for `*(A+i)`, but when `A` is an iterator, it's a function call.

Efficient vectorization requires the compiler to spot that the write to `A[i]` does not affect subsequent reads from `temp[i]`, which is a non-trivial observation. There's no loop-carried dependency, but the optimizer must be able to prove it.

Comment: In other words, there is nothing illegal about the iterator case, but it is simply to complex for the optimizer to understand it. To be honest, for the double case, the gain is quite small. However for floats, with 4 values being processed simultaneously by the vector unit, the effect is around a factor of 2.

Comment: @PaulR.: Personally I'd write it as a old-fashioned linear addition using AVX. All those writes to `A[ ]` will hurt; you're going to be bandwidth-limited for such a simple operation.

Comment: Sound promising. I'll check that out.